# Re-indexing Cosmos DB progress always returning -1

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a 100GB Cosmos DB collection that I'm applying a new index policy to.  After setting the new index policy, calls to the `ReadDocumentCollectionAsync` C# API always reports a value of `IndexTransformationProgress` with -1.  I've checked the HTTP headers and the `x-ms-documentdb-collection-index-transformation-progress` header is also -1.

Running a query on a field with a range index, I can see the index gradually being rebuilt if I use an order by clause.  I've tried using different consistencies and lazy loading, but progress is always reported as -1.  I can't find what this means in the online documentation.

How can I determine when the index has been rebuilt, and get the progress of a rebuild in progress?

I'm using the NuGet package version 1.18.0.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Editor: This answer is now out of date*

I am from Cosmos DB engineering team. The IndexTransformationProgress header is not supported for partitioned collection currently. '-1' means unknown or not applicable. Sorry for the inconvenience. We are evaluating and planning to support it in near future.

Comment: Is there any other way to know if an index is in the process of being rebuilt?

Comment: @TomLi any update on this? Or any way to monitor an index on a partitioned collection?

Answer (score 4):

I am from the CosmosDB engineering team.

We do have transformation progress now for a partitioned collections - this was released recently. This can be fetched by setting the header 'x-ms-documentdb-populatequotainfo' to True. This header, in addition to providing quota and usage information for a partitioned collection, is also used to piggyback the index transformation progress information for partitioned collections.